# Bind List<string> to a column of Grid View in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="reportScheduleDetailsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >                
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Frequency" HeaderText="Frequency" ></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reports" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="cblSubscribedReports" Text='<%# Eval("Reports") %>'  runat="server"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
               DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("Name");
                table.Columns.Add("Frequency");
                table.Columns.Add("Reports");

                DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
                row1["Name"] = "A";
                row1["Frequency"] = "Daily";
                    List<string> report1 = new List<string>();
                    report1.Add("XYZ");
                    report1.Add("ABC");
                    report1.Add("PQR");
                    row1["Reports"] = report1;
                table.Rows.Add(row1);

                DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
                row2["Name"] = "B";
                row2["Frequency"] = "Weekly";
                    List<string> report2 = new List<string>();
                    report2.Add("XYZ");
                row2["Reports"] = report2;
                table.Rows.Add(row2);

                reportScheduleDetailsGridView.DataSource = table;
                reportScheduleDetailsGridView.DataBind();
```

When I run the code Reports column shows System.Collections.Generic instead of string values

```
Name    Frequency       Reports
A           Daily         System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] 
B           Weekly        System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

I need the output like this: Report column should show the list of string

```
Name    Frequency   Reports
A            Daily            1.XYZ
                          2.ABC
                          3.PQR
B           Weekly            1.XYZ
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you shold specify the data type of the Reports column:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Frequency");
        table.Columns.Add("Reports", typeof(List<string>));

        DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
        row1["Name"] = "A";
        row1["Frequency"] = "Daily";
        List<string> report1 = new List<string>();
        report1.Add("XYZ");
        report1.Add("ABC");
        report1.Add("PQR");
        row1["Reports"] = report1;
        table.Rows.Add(row1);

        DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
        row2["Name"] = "B";
        row2["Frequency"] = "Weekly";
        List<string> report2 = new List<string>();
        report2.Add("XYZ");
        row2["Reports"] = report2;
        table.Rows.Add(row2);

        reportScheduleDetailsGridView.DataSource = table;
        reportScheduleDetailsGridView.DataBind();


<asp:GridView ID="reportScheduleDetailsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Frequency" HeaderText="Frequency"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reports">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Reports") %>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# (Container.ItemIndex+1)+"."+ Container.DataItem  %><br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
report1.Add("1.XYZ");
row1["Reports"] = string.Join("<br />", report1);
I don’t like to append the number to the report name in the list and adding new line “<br />” to string. Join in the code file.
 Can we add this logic to the designer page?

Comment: @user2323308 Yes, see my updated answer, it will solve your problem.

Comment: It returns string System.Collections.Generic.List
Result is like this.
Name Frequency Reports
A Daily 1. S
                2.y

Comment: Did you notice this line has changed?   table.Columns.Add("Reports", typeof(List<string>));

Comment: Oh... I have not noticed.
Thanks you very much. It Worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can show the value comma seprated like this

```
   DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
   row2["Name"] = "B";
   row2["Frequency"] = "Weekly";
   List<string> report2 = new List<string>();
   report2.Add("XYZ");
   string strReports = string.Join(",", report2.ToArray());
   row2["Reports"] = strReports ;
   table.Rows.Add(row2);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, I would only replace the comma by a newline as he is trying to show each report on a newline (in the same row).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show the object in the column. The Label in your TemplateColumn does not know how to show a list of string-values. You should place a string in the Label, like so:

```
int i = 2;
var res = "1. " + report1.Aggregate((c, n) => c + String.Format("\r\n{0}. {1}", i++, n));
row1["Reports"] = res;
```

That will give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

GridView cannot automatically figure out how to present a collection.

You can put another data bound control(ListView or GridView) inside the Reports column and then bind that to the list of reports on an event like RowDataBound.

Refer: [Hierarchical Data Binding in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478959.aspx)

```
      <ItemTemplate>        
        <asp:Repeater Runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
             DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Reports")%>'>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <br/><asp:Label ID="cblSubscribedReports" 
                  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Report") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
      </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Code throws exception: DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'Report'.

Comment: :-) I didn't say, you should copy paste it to make it work. `Report` is the name of the property from the list you want rendered.

Comment: If you want only a list of strings, just use `<%# Container.DataItem %>`